# Google sheet Pivot table - group by different rows coming from different fields

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

I need to reproduce an excel pivot table into googlesheet. Say you have fields with info about a Payer and other fields with info about the seller. All fields must go in the Rows section of the Pivot table. Would anyone know a way to place the fields corresponding to the buyer (example: buyer name,buyer address) under each other and the fields corresponding to the seller under each other as well ?

I have tried Group By but this seem to work only with values of the same field.

Here is a link to a googlesheet I created showing what I want to do (sheet1) and sheet2 has some data to try for this pivot table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJvlLsijsnzKbSvgLVYkGEzcA3MdpSJZIMYquy26dGM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I would like to help you, but it is not clear to me what exactly you mean. Could you provide a screenshot or maybe show how you have it in your Excel file? How do you want to reproduce the table? Do you copy all the data from which you are gonna create the pivot table into Google Sheets? or do you want to copy the actual entries of the pivot table?

Comment: Hi @ziganotschka, sure. Here is a link to a sheet I created explaining what I want to do: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJvlLsijsnzKbSvgLVYkGEzcA3MdpSJZIMYquy26dGM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: First sheet shows two screenshots: the upper one with what I have tried with my googlesheet and the one underneath with what I used to have with Excel... In excel, the rows of fields like BP Number and BP Name can go underneath each other...in googlesheet I can't get the same result

Comment: In Sheet2, I provide a mini test with 4 different columns. The thing is, all fields must go in the 'ROWS' section of the pivot table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to make the pivot table look like this:

[image]

The easiest way to achieve it would be a workaround, which implies your initial data be looking like this:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

Changing the layout of your table automatically can be achieved with Apps Script. 
Here an example code, how you can create from your original data  in sheet `originalData` a “Pivot table friendly” representation in sheet `newLayout`:

```
  function myFunction() {
  var originalData=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('originalData');
  var newLayout=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('newLayout');
  var limit=originalData.getLastRow();
  var BuyerName=originalData.getRange('A2:A'+limit);
  var BuyerPayer=originalData.getRange('B2:B'+limit);
  var SellerName=originalData.getRange('C2:C'+limit);
  var SellerPayer=originalData.getRange('D2:D'+limit);
  var header=newLayout.getRange('A1:C1');
  var transaction1=newLayout.getRange('A2:A'+limit);
  var transaction2=newLayout.getRange('A'+(limit+1)+':A'+(2*limit-1)); 
  var buyer1=newLayout.getRange('B2:B'+limit); 
  var buyer2=newLayout.getRange('B'+(limit+1)+':B'+(2*limit-1)); 
  var seller1=newLayout.getRange('C2:C'+limit); 
  var seller2=newLayout.getRange('C'+(limit+1)+':C'+(2*limit-1));  
  header.setValues([['Transaction', 'Buyer', 'Seller']]);   
  for(var i=1;i<limit;i++)
  {
    transaction1.getCell(i,1).setValue(i);
    transaction2.getCell(i,1).setValue(i);
    buyer1.getCell(i,1).setValue(BuyerName.getCell(i,1).getValue());
    buyer2.getCell(i,1).setValue(BuyerPayer.getCell(i,1).getValue());
    seller1.getCell(i,1).setValue(SellerName.getCell(i,1).getValue());
    seller2.getCell(i,1).setValue(SellerPayer.getCell(i,1).getValue());
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to lean on this problem. I have way too many columns to do it this way so I am not using the solution. I just added the fields one after the other. But thanks :) @ziganotschka